# What does "last hill" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), J.J confronts Dallas,
who is in love with J.J's sister Susan:

> Dallas: I'm here as an average Joe who happens to love your sister.
>
> J.J: Well, just be careful you don't knock her off her feet, hmm?
> Stanley, move it to your right a little bit. Now, frankly, son, I lost
> you on that **last hill**.

What does "last hill" mean?

Comment: Some more context would help. Are they perhaps *walking* through hilly territory? Also, is JJ speaking to Dallas or Stanley? It probably won't make much difference though. JJ's last sentence has effectively no meaning at all without context, and *with* context the meaning should be obvious. Certainly ***on that last hill*** isn't an idiom with an established meaning.

Comment: ...but I *suspect* JJ "misspoke", and what he really means is ***You** lost **me*** (I ceased to be able to understand what you were talking about). Native speakers do sometime "invert" the logical subject and object in such constructions, even if it apparently makes no sense to do so.

Comment: @FumbleFingers JJ is speaking to Dallas not Stanley.

Comment: Guessing wildly, might JJ and Dallas be playing a round of golf, and Stanley is the ***caddy***? Golf courses often have little hills all over the place

Comment: Here **son** is Dallas.

Comment: And where is the conversation taking place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens, I have access to that movie *with subtitles*, so I found the relevant fragment at 1:04.05.

Note that the context is a busy movie set, where ***Stanley, move it to your right a little bit*** is just an irrelevant bit of dialogue going on in the background.

JJ (Burt Lancaster) is (sloppily?) mixing a couple of different metaphors. The *second* one *(Just give us the **punchline**)* alludes to a comedian telling a joke (itself metaphorically derived from boxing's ***knockout punch***). JJ means ***Get to the point**!*

The *first* metaphoric usage *(You lost me on that last **hill**)* never had any currency, but the meaning is clear enough to this native speaker *(...on that last **thing you just said**)*.

My guess is it's at least *associated* with *That's not **a hill to die on*** (it's not a point worth fighting to the death over), which is metaphorically derived from the military context of lengthy / costly fighting to defend / overrun militarily strategic positions.

Figuratively speaking, there's the well-established ***garden path sentence***, which draws a parallel between ***following a train of thought*** expressed in words and walking along a (winding) path. JJ's usage just stretches that into *"**walking over hill and dale**"* - with a guide who might drop out of sight behind the last / next hill<sup>1</sup>, in certain circumstances (such as a long line of thinly-spread Wild West *pioneers' wagons*).

---

Note that *most* native speakers<sup>2</sup> would say ***You** lost **me** there* (you didn't express yourself clearly enough for me), rather than ***I** lost **you** there* (I failed to understand, perhaps because I wasn't paying attention). But both versions are "almost" equivalent, and would rarely be explicitly differentiated by either speaker or audience.

---

<sup>1</sup> It belatedly occurs to me that just as the metaphor works with both ***You** lost **me*** and ***I** lost **you***, either party to the "communications breakdown" might be figuratively behind the ***last*** or ***next*** hill. Assume whichever makes most sense to you.

<sup>2</sup> I should have [checked!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=You%20lost%20me%20there%2CI%20lost%20you%20there&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) For most of my life, the ***You** lost **me*** version was twice as common as ***I** lost **you***. But the position has reversed over the last decade or two (no-one is ever going to convince me that the usage shift relates to *changed circumstances / different meanings*).